# Estoy haciendo un juego del ahorcado con java pero sin usar array y al intentar concatenar no me sale

Tags: java

Al intentar concatenar la letra con la variable auxiliar, la letra no se pone en la posición que deberia.
Y si ya alguien me ayuda con el tema de hacer 5 intentos pues lo agradecería pero muchisimo.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String palabra;
        String aux = " ";
        char letra;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Inserte una palabra: ");
        palabra = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.print("La palabra insertada es " + palabra);
        do {
            System.out.print("Inserte un letra: ");
            letra = scanner.nextLine().charAt(0);

            for (int pos = 0; pos < palabra.length(); pos++) {
                if (palabra.charAt(pos) == letra) {
                    aux = aux + letra.charAt(pos);
                    System.out.println(letra);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("_");
                }
            }
        } while (aux != palabra);
        System.out.println("Muy bien jugado");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Había un error de compilación en el código que habías puesto. Pero aún así, el problema con esa forma de hacerlo, es que cada vuelta del bucle `do-while` iba añadiendo el string a aux por lo que se duplicaba la palabra. Lo he hecho con el método `substring` de la clase `String` que creo que es lo que necesita menores conocimientos para entender la solución. También se podría hacer con la clase `StringBuilder` y posiblemente con otras.

Por otra parte, (para la condición del `while`) las cadenas no se deben comparar con los operadores `==` o `!=` porque no siempre funciona. Lo suyo es usar el método `equals`.

Para hacer lo de los 5 intentos puedes utilizar un contador que se vaya incrementando.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
            String palabra;
            String aux = "";
            char letra;

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Inserte una palabra: ");
            palabra = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("La palabra insertada es " + palabra);
            for(int i=0;i<palabra.length();i++){
                aux+="_";
            }
            do {
                System.out.println("Inserte un letra: ");
                letra = scanner.next().charAt(0);

                for (int pos = 0; pos < palabra.length(); pos++) {
                    if(pos==0 && palabra.charAt(pos) == letra) {
                        aux=letra+aux.substring(1);
                    }else if (palabra.charAt(pos) == letra) {
                        aux = aux.substring(0, pos)+letra+aux.substring(pos+1);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(aux);
            } while (!aux.equals(palabra));     
                System.out.println("Muy bien jugado");      

}
```